# HikariCP Lazy with Spring LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy

Tags: spring, hikaricp

Can a HikariCP Datasource be started with a Lazy configuration?

For that, i'm using Spring [LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC1/javadoc-api/).

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="poolName" value="TargetHikariCP" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
    <property name="connectionInitSql" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
    <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="300000"/>
    <property name="minimumIdle" value="1"/>
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="autoCommit" value="false"/>
    <property name="dataSourceProperties"> <props> ... </props> </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceLazy" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource" ref="dataSourceLazy" />
</bean>      


<bean id="txManager"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Nevertheless, its not working, as the Datasource is started on project startup.

The same configuration, when using a [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC1/javadoc-api/), works correctly.

Comment: No, as HikariCP is a proper connection pool which will fetch connections during startup. The `DriverManagerDataSource` isn't a connection pool and as such creates connection to the database when needed (and that is generally a time consuming process).

Answer (score 4):

In the version > 3 we can set `setInitializationFailTimeout(-1);`

According to docs:

- Any value greater than zero will be treated as a timeout for pool initialization.The calling thread will be blocked from continuing until a successful connection
  to the database, or until the timeout is reached.  If the timeout is reached, then
  a `PoolInitializationException` will be thrown.
- A value of zero will not  prevent the pool from starting in the
  case that a connection cannot be obtained. However, upon start the pool will
  attempt to obtain a connection and validate that the `connectionTestQuery`
  and `connectionInitSql` are valid.  If those validations fail, an exception
  will be thrown.  If a connection cannot be obtained, the validation is skipped
  and the the pool will start and continue to try to obtain connections in the
  background.  This can mean that callers to `DataSource#getConnection()` may
  encounter exceptions.
- A value less than zero will bypass any connection attempt and validation during
  startup, and therefore the pool will start immediately.  The pool will continue to
  try to obtain connections in the background. This can mean that callers to
  `DataSource#getConnection()` may encounter exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

HikariCP has a property, ***initializationFailFast***, that controls whether the pool will "fail fast" if the pool cannot be seeded with initial connections successfully:

> This property controls whether the pool will "fail fast" if the pool cannot be seeded with initial connections successfully. If you want your application to start even when the database is down/unavailable, set this property to false. Default: true

This property was documented in their site, but per version 2.6.2 its not, but it seems its still supported.

In my use case, the use of this property should be enough to solve my problem.

Comment: Please note that this answer is not valid anymore since version 3.x. See https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/9fef2256149bc111396e7b23e3c54b1de0cd66fd/CHANGES for changelog. It has been removed in favor of `initializationFailTimeout` configuration property.